# Prove that the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent series of positive numbers and set $r_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n$. Prove that the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

**Solution I have tried**

By definition, $r_n=a_n+r_{n+1}$. Hence,

$\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}=1-\frac{a_n}{r_n}$,

$\frac{r_{n+2}}{r_n}=\big(1-\frac{a_n}{r_n}\big)\big(1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{r_{n+1}}\big)>1-\frac{a_n}{r_n}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{r_{n+1}}$.

By induction we have 
$\frac{r_{n+p}}{r_n}>1-\frac{a_n}{r_n}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{r_{n+1}}- \dots \frac{a_{n+p}}{r_{n+p}}$.

As the series $\sum a_n$ is conv, we have that $r_{n+p} \to 0$ as $p \to \infty$.

Now what? I am stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your definition of $r_n$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: 'By definition, $r_n=a_n+a_{n+1}$'- How?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. @Jose I am sorry for the typo.